# Oracle SQL, Combine Update or Merge with Join, Insert Surrogate Keys into Fact table using 2 dimensions tables

Tags: sql, oracle, etl, data-warehouse

I have populated my dimension tables (**Oracle SQL Dev**.) For the next step I created the **`facts table` (F_Orders)**, I **loaded quantity, price** , the **Order_ID's** and `surrogate keys` into the `facts table`.

**I want to Insert the latest Surrogate_ID's (customer, location, etc.) with the specific `record`.**
In **SA_ORDERS** I can see which Order_ID is connected with which Customer_ID. Using Customer_ID in **D_CUSTOMERS** I can find the `Surrogate key`.

To perform this task, I used this query:

```
INSERT INTO F_Orders 
(order_id
,quanity
,price
,cust_s_key)
       
SELECT
sa_order_items.order_id
,sa_order_items.quantity
,sa_order_items.unit_price
,d_customers.s_key
FROM
sa_order_items
JOIN sa_orders ON sa_order_items.order_id = sa_orders.order_id
JOIN d_customers ONd_customers.customer_id=sa_orders.customer_id
WHERE 
d_customers."Latest" = 'Y'
AND d_customers.flag = 'I'
```

Now I was wondering, can I perform `update` for `Surrogate key` (cust_s_key) as I have 2 `joints` to use?
Unfortunately, I cant combine `update` with the `join` successfully. How could I **combine** both or **may find another way** to do it? Thanks a lot in advance.
PS. I know that in the `ETL` we won't need this update often.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statements for a minimal example; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; your expected output; and an explanation of which columns you are talking about.

Comment: Dear MT0, I tried my best to add language identifier and edit the text. Please let me know if I can do more.

Comment: Quick question, Why are you updating your fact table after loading it? are you not supposed to load the latest surrogate keys as part of the load itself once the dimensions are loaded?

Comment: Hi Sunil, thank you very much for your quick answer. Yes absolutely correct, I do it this way. Sorry for the confusion, I changed the post. I was just wondering If I Initlitay didn't bring all surrogate keys, can I still update later even I have 2 joints?

Comment: Hi - what is/are the reason(s) for running updates? Because the customer wasn’t known when the fact record was created; because the fact was associated to the wrong customer; because the wrong record for the correct customer was used (customer records held as SCD)?

Comment: Hi Nick, it was just a request if it's possible to do that. Normally the record should stay untouched after it was inserted correctly. Thank you to everyone who helped to solve my question 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can update the fact table using the same query

```
UPDATE F_Orders fo SET fo.cust_s_key = (SELECT
distinct d_customers.s_key
FROM
sa_order_items
JOIN sa_orders ON sa_order_items.order_id = sa_orders.order_id
JOIN d_customers ONd_customers.customer_id=sa_orders.customer_id
WHERE 
d_customers."Latest" = 'Y'
AND d_customers.flag = 'I'
AND sa_order_items.order_id = fo.order_id)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM
sa_order_items
JOIN sa_orders ON sa_order_items.order_id = sa_orders.order_id
JOIN d_customers ONd_customers.customer_id=sa_orders.customer_id
WHERE 
d_customers."Latest" = 'Y'
AND d_customers.flag = 'I'
AND sa_order_items.order_id = fo.order_id)
```

Comment: Works! Perfect, thank you so much, this query worked.